# mongodb - sort a sub-document object by its property values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-aggregation

i have a document in mongodb as follows.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57960sdsf3442d52da19836f"),
    "name" : "test",
    "values" : {
        "value1" : 7,
        "value2" : 9,
        "value3" : 10,
        "value4" : 1,
        "value5" : 3,
        "value6" : 4,
    }
}
```

so i want to write a query in such a way that i get the `values` object sorted by it's values. as follows:

```
 "values" : {
        "value3" : 10,
        "value2" : 9,
        "value1" : 7,
        "value6" : 4,
        "value5" : 3,
        "value4" : 1,
    }
```

so i basically want the content of the field in a descending order.

Comment: @Tom it didn't help...my key values are different..not able to specify on which field sort have to be done.

Comment: oh, you have to emphasize it in your question...

Comment: does the properties names are constant? does it have to be object? why not array?